# Select in Tapestry with name not id

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, tapestry

I'm working with select component in Tapestry. I want to select one object in form, and I want it to show names in select options, but it shows id instead.

TML:

```
        <t:beaneditform object="soba" exclude="idSobe" add="idHotel" >
         <p:idHotel>
        <t:label for="idHotel"/>:
         <t:select t:blankLabel="Odaberi Hotel" t:id="idHotel"  
          encoder="encoder" model="hoteli" value="idHotel"
        />
        </p:idHotel>
        </t:beaneditform>
```

Java:

```
        @Property
       private Soba onesoba;
         @Inject 
        private HotelDao hotelDao;
        @Property
         private Hotel idHotel;
         @Property
          @Persist
          private List<Hotel> hoteli;
         @Property
            private List<Soba>sobe;


      public ValueEncoder getEncoder() {
      return new ValueEncoder<Hotel>() {
       @Override
     public String toClient(Hotel v) {
       return String.valueOf(v.getIdHotel());
      }
      @Override
    public Hotel toValue(String string) {
      Hotel hot = hotelDao.getHotelById(Integer.parseInt(string));
       return hot;
       }
```

And when I run the app and want to select an obj I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClDhz.png)

But when clicking on "add hotel" I want name property not :com.mycompany...

If someone has any suggestion how to change that property in select component, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a SelectModel, specifying which property to be shown.

```
...
@Property
@Persist
private List<Hotel> hoteli;

@Inject
private SelectModelFactory smf;

public SelectModel getHoteliModel()
{
  return smf.create(hoteli, "name") ;
}
...
```

And in your .tml you'll have:

```
<t:select t:blankLabel="Odaberi Hotel" t:id="idHotel"  
      encoder="encoder" model="hoteliModel" value="idHotel"
```